# Install python packages in windows server 2016 which has no internet connection

Tags: python, windows, windows-server-2016

I need to install python packages in a windows server 2016 sandbox for running a developed python model in production.This doesn't have internet connection.

My laptop is windows 2010 and the model is now running in my machine and need to push this to the server.

My question is how can i install all the required packages in my server which has no internet connection.

Thanks
Mithun

Answer (score 1):

For the windows server machine make sure you have `pip` installed and added to path.

Then proceed with the following steps:

1. Since you are using windows try to download the packages from [Unofficial Python Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) in your personal laptop that has an internet connection. Try to download the `whl` file.
2. Copy / transfer the downloaded `whl` file to the windows server machine.
3. Use `pip` to install the copied / transferred `whl` file.

```
pip install <filname>.whl
```

If you dont want to install any mathematical packages, you can use the official [Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/) repository.

Proceed with the following steps to download a Python Library from the Official Library:

1. Open the Official [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) page.
2. Search for your required package (e.g., I am searching for a library named `beautifulsoup4` [link](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/))
3. You need to select `Download Files` from the side menu. [e.g.,](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#files)
4. Download the required version `whl` file.
5. Copy / transfer the downloaded `whl` file to the windows server machine.
6. Use `pip` to install the copied / transferred `whl` file.

Comment: Thanks , But you will end up using unofficial packages in this case ?

Comment: Actually the Python libraries work perfectly for Ubuntu, some libraries might give some issues in windows, So the mentioned site has Windows binaries of many scientific open-source extension packages for the official CPython distribution of the Python programming language.

Answer (score 0):

A simply way is to install the same python version on another machine having internet access, and use normally pip on that machine. This will download a bunch of files and installs them cleanly under `Lib\site_packages` of your Python installation.

You can they copy that folder to the server Python installation. If you want to be able to later add packages, you should keep both installations in sync: do not add or remove any package on the laptop without syncing with the server.